# NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.SparkContext.ui()Lscala/Option

Tags: apache-spark

I was trying Spark examples using 1.6.0 with Maven

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

and here is the code

```
JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
SparkContext sc = JavaSparkContext.toSparkContext(jsc);
SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(jsc);
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.SparkContext.ui()Lscala/Option;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$.createListenerAndUI(SQLContext.scala:1369)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.(SQLContext.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.(SQLContext.scala:79)
    at KmeansPixelsJava.main(KmeansPixelsJava.java:24)

Can someone help me on what i am missing?

Thanks,
Rishi

Answer (score 0):

This exception sometimes occurs when launching your application against a different version of Spark. Make sure that you submit your job with the same version of Spark as in your Maven dependencies. (would make this a comment but I don't have enough rep)

More [info](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html)

Comment: Thanks Rudy. Later I was able to figure out that I had one more jar included (fat jar) which also had the spark packages within them. Due to that the spark classes were overridden and caused the issue.